# Pandas use series to select column names

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

If I have a series ('A','B') that I pulled in as a column from pandas.read_csv,
how can I use it to select columns from a data frame like this?

```
pd.DataFrame={'A':[1,2,3],'B':[2,3,4]}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please post working code because that line does not make sense, it could be replacing the constructor of the pandas DataFrame

Answer (score 0):

I had to change it to a list and pass it as the columns like this:

```
list=list(series)
df=df[list]
```